# Trouble with triggers and scope identity

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, scope-identity

Trying to create a trigger that makes a duplicate record of every record in a database but adds the word duplicate and the date on the end. It is based on a table with only two fields (records int has identity_specification) and (value nvarchar(256)). First record inserts correctly, second record always returns null. What am I doing wrong here. First attempt to learn triggers and this is a nonsense application just for the purpose of understanding, but it will help me with my next project. Thanks!

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_InsertNew] ON [dbo].[TrigTest]
AFTER INSERT
AS

declare @mess nvarchar(245)

set @mess = (select trigtest.value from trigtest where trigtest.record = SCOPE_IDENTITY()) + ' Duplicate ' + convert(nvarchar(12), GETDATE())

insert into trigtest
select @mess
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Switched to `ON UPDATE` and got it to work.